# POST url with Curl PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a thank you page with URL that contains variables :

http://vieillemethodecorpsneuf.com/confirmation-achat-1a/?item=1&cbreceipt=VM6JQ6VE&time=1429212702&cbpop=C123FA24&cbaffi=twitpalace&cname=Roberto+Laplante&cemail=roberto%40gmail.com&ccountry=FR&czip=000

I have this GET function to catch the variables :

```
<?php
$clickbank_name = (isset($_GET['cname'])) ? $_GET['cname'] : ''; 
$clickbank_email = (isset($_GET['cemail'])) ? $_GET['cemail'] : '';
$clickbank_country = (isset($_GET['ccountry'])) ? $_GET['ccountry'] : '';
$clickbank_zip = (isset($_GET['czip'])) ? $_GET['czip'] : '';
$clickbank_aff = (isset($_GET['cbaffi'])) ? $_GET['cbaffi'] : '';
?>
```

Now I need to use curl PHP to send the data to that Zapier URL (but with the variables attached to it so it will give me) :

https://zapier.com/hooks/catch/bheq6y/?tag=client&cbaffi=twitpalace&cname=Roberto+Laplante&cemail=roberto%40gmail.com&ccountry=FR&czip=000

*ps. I have added a manual tag to the URL*

What would be the PHP Curl code to make this work? Need to be behind the scene operation.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it a shot.

```
$get_fields = ['tag' => 'client'];
if (isset($_GET['cname'])) $get_fields['cname'] = $_GET['cname'];
if (isset($_GET['cemail'])) $get_fields['cemail'] = $_GET['cemail'];
if (isset($_GET['ccountry'])) $get_fields['ccountry'] = $_GET['ccountry'];
if (isset($_GET['czip'])) $get_fields['czip'] = $_GET['czip'];
if (isset($_GET['cbaffi'])) $get_fields['cbaffi'] = $_GET['cbaffi'];

$encoded = '';
foreach($get_fields as $name => $value){
    $encoded .= urlencode($name).'='.urlencode($value).'&';
}

$url = 'https://zapier.com/hooks/catch/bheq6y/?'.rtrim($encoded,'&');

// simple get curl
$output = file_get_contents($url);

// or if you want more control over the request
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
));
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Good it worked But, got that error on that line : 

    $get_fields = ['tag' => 'client'];

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/diete3sem/public_html/test2.php on line 43

When I remove it, the code is working well, but I don't have the tag. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just change it with ```$get_fields = array('tag' => 'client')``` the ```[]``` syntax is array notation for PHP >= 5.4 and you must be runing 5.3 (you should upgrade your PHP installation, 5.3 is eol)

Comment: Is it safe to upgrade to 5.4 with all my actual php code that is working on 5.3. And wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

In this example, we are posting data in parameters to another curl.php page and in curl.php, 
 i wrote some code to get executed whenever curl.php get called and the result will be sent back to page from where curl.php got a request. 
 Mechanism : This example is made in PHP using Curl.

First Step : Create curl.php file. That file will be called by another php file by using curl mechanism. 
 So in curl.php we will get some parameters. We get parameters and do some functionalities. After that when we desire output, 
 we just encode with json using json_encode() and simple echo.

```
$post = $_POST;
echo json_encode($post);
```

Note : index.php will get the data in json format because we are sending back data in json format to index.php

Second Step : we have to create an index.php file. Where we write a logic for executiing a curl with some parameters and then call curl.php and get result from curl.php
    $url = 'http://localhost/curl_demo/curl.php'; // This is my targeted file(curl.php) that i want to execute when curl executed
    $ch = curl_init($url);

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'id=1&name=sanjay'); // pass parameters to curl.php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$resArr = json_decode($response, true);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($resArr);
```

Note: The data that we get after curl executed successfully, we will get it in json format. That means we have to decode it using json_decode() in php.